# AttributeError: type object 'h5py.h5.H5PYConfig' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'

Tags: python-3.x, h5py

I've tried to reinstall h5py hdp5 etc.
My conda version is 4.9.2 python 3.8.5
Is there anyone with a similar issue ? Is there an alternative to h5py ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\X_train.h5\test.py", line 17, in <module>
    import h5py

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import version

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\version.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import h5 as _h5

  File "h5py\h5.pyx", line 1, in init h5py.h5

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing defs: La procédure spécifiée est introuvable.


runfile('D:/X_train.h5/test.py', wdir='D:/X_train.h5')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\X_train.h5\test.py", line 17, in <module>
    import h5py

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import version

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\version.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import h5 as _h5

  File "h5py\h5.pyx", line 41, in init h5py.h5

AttributeError: type object 'h5py.h5.H5PYConfig' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a fixed bug in the h5py's interface.
Try:

```
pip install --upgrade h5py
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: The OP is using an Anaconda distribution. Using pip to install packages installed/managed/available from conda, will potentially corrupt the environment.

Answer (score 2):

You should try:

```
pip install h5py==2.9
```

Comment: The OP is using an Anaconda distribution. Using pip to install packages installed/managed/available from conda, will potentially corrupt the environment.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall all older h5py. Then  this command:

```
conda install -c anaconda h5py
```

Answer (score 0):

Some packages like tensorflow 2.6 need you to downgrade h5py. Try `pip install h5py==3.1`

Comment: The OP is using an Anaconda distribution. Using pip to install packages installed/managed/available from conda, will potentially corrupt the environment.

Answer (score 0):

**Refer this image:**

[image: Refer this image]

```
pip install --upgrade h5py
```

This will update your package and tell us the right version needed for Tensorflow

```
pip install h5py==version
```

In my case, I had TensorFlow 2.5.0 which needed h5py=3.1.0

Comment: The OP is using an Anaconda distribution. Using pip to remove/install packages installed/managed/available from conda, will potentially corrupt the environment.